# How to achieve this in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table:

[image]

I want to `GROUP BY` category and then select only top 2 product's `Name`, `Category`, and `Rating`.

So final output should be like this:

```
Id      Name      Category      Rating
1       Iphone    Electronics   5
7       MI        Electronics   5
4       Top       Fashion       5
9       Shoes     Fashion       5
10      Coffe     Food          5
11      jAM       Food          4
```

I tried to solve via my way but still no luck.
I want the top 2 result from every category based on rating if one category have two products of the same rating like 5 then result should show both.

I am new on stackOverFlow thats my first question i doesn't know much about the manners and rules but i will learn.

Sorry if i breaks any rule.

Comment: How do you define the top two products? Are you ordering by the name?

Comment: What happens when you have more than two products in a category that have a `5` rating?  How are you determining which two of those you should return?

Comment: overall top 2 products name or top 2 product of a particular category.

Comment: @RahulSingh i want all columns(Id Name Category Rating)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select * 
from (
  select *, 
    rank() over (partition by Category order by Rating desc) as Rank
  from yourtable
) X
where Rank <= 2
```

You might want to look the differences of rank vs dense_rank in case you have the same rating.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply but it doesn't solve what i am looking for for e.g I want the top 2 result from every category based on rating if one category have two products of the same rating like 5 then result should show both. But stil i learned from ur answer.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with ties. You can also use row_number() to get exactly 2 results.